# execution of some code inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with some example code in it. I'd like to execute this code after pressing a button. Here's what I've tried:

HTML

```
<button onclick="javascript:playcode()"> </button>
```

JS

```
function playcode () {
     var execcode= "";
     for (i=1; i<=countCodeLine (); i++)
         execcode += document.getElementById("line"+i).innerText;

     var div= document.getElementById ("mydiv");
     var scr= document.createElement ('script', "");
     div.innerHTML= "play() {"+execcode+"}";
     div.appendChild(scr);
     play();
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can i do this?

UPDATE: here the errors from the console:

```
(line 9: pre.appendChild(scr)) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 
(line 10: play()) Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: what does not work? Do you get any errors? (You don't need the named jump label `javascript:` btw if you don't use `break` or things like that).

Comment: There's no reason this doesn't work, except if the onclick attribute was changed or the javascript not loaded.

Comment: Include all HTML code ...

Comment: it looks like you could just use an `eval` here to get the exact functionality.

Comment: @JustinL. you mean directly  eval (execcode); ???

Comment: @Jannuzzo yep, `eval(execcode)` is better

Comment: not sure but maybe `scr.innerHTML= "function play() {"+execcode+"}";`

Comment: Where is pre getting set? Is there even a function named play()?

Comment: thank you all.. works with the eval function.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed getting the right HTML into execcode, you can use

```
eval(execcode);
```

You can check this by just doing a simple `console.log(execcode)` or `alert(execcode)` to verify that it's loaded correctly.

However, I can guarantee you that this is **almost certainly a very, very bad idea**.  it'd be trivial for someone to just edit your DOM and insert whatever malicious javascript they want.

Comment: you're welcome, but remember that you probably shouldn't do this in a production environment.